# Set starting position for aggregate function?

Tags: r

I'm counting the number of occurrences for each 100kb section (bins) in my data, using `start` and `end` columns. I have used `aggregate`for that purpose.

Data sample:

```
    chr   start    end   length  abs_summit pileup   X.log10.pvalue. fold_enrichment
1  chr1   10004   10586    583      10076    288       262.84540        19.37227
2  chr1   28946   29387    442      29309     59        37.01597         8.33123
3  chr1  384456  386620   2165     385473     38        30.88671        10.66657
4  chr1  544777  546003   1227     545467     46        29.03529         7.95905
5  chr1  546962  547834    873     547696     37        21.86056         6.93344
6  chr1  564682  565377    696     565177   2396       801.42346         4.73626
7  chr1  565647  565859    213     565768   2225       677.54956         4.33460
8  chr1  566082  566749    668     566207   2363       767.32574         4.60286
9  chr1  567264  567682    419     567385   2559       900.85590         4.98421
10 chr1  569289  569585    297     569395   1994       535.04041         3.88158
11 chr1  603864  605365   1502     604917     28        20.02823         8.06871
12 chr1  713780  714492    713     714122     80        62.03205        12.10543
13 chr1  726303  726397     95     726331     35        20.22534         6.65208
14 chr1  726902  727015    114     726956     38        23.21246         7.27584
15 chr1  762303  763398   1096     762976     50        28.46482         7.09851
16 chr1  894589  894800    212     894677     58        28.29763         6.05185
17 chr1  912206  912835    630     912372     60        25.23332         5.16066
18 chr1 1013683 1014743   1061    1013926     67        28.39317         5.28122
19 chr1 1051254 1052109    856    1051607     76        45.31027         8.12284
20 chr1 1092833 1093509    677    1092949     50        21.65445         5.17642
```

Code to make bins each 100kb:

`normal_count1 = aggregate(end ~ chr + start%/%100000, data=normal, FUN=length)`

Which results in:

```
       chr   x100Kb   occurrences_norm  
1      chr1     0             2
39     chr1     3             1
56     chr1     5             7
67     chr1     6             1
79     chr1     7             4
91     chr1     8             1
102    chr1     9             1
```

Where `x100kb` is the bin number.

However, I would like to add a new 'reading frame' starting in the position 50000 (so bin number 1 would go from 50kb to 150kb,bin number 2 from 150 to 250, etc). I have tried using `aggregate` again, but this hasn't worked (it's adding 50000 to the start value, I think):

`normal_count2 = aggregate(end ~ chr + (start+50000)%/%100000, data=normal, FUN=length)`

Is there any way of doing this with `aggregate` or is there a more appropiate function I should use?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it's more clear now. Basically, I would like to count the number of rows in each bin for each chromosome as I did in the example; but instead of starting with the first bin at `start=0`; I would like to start making the bins at `start=50000`.

Comment: Did you try to subset the data? `aggregate(end ~ chr + start%/%100000, data=normal[normal$start > 50000,], FUN=length)`

Comment: instead of using `%/%` you could try the `cut` function

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work; it ignores the peaks with `start<50000` but still makes the bins since 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out what the issue you are seeing but instead tried to follow your description of what was wanted. I used a modified dataset with values that spanned the first desired boundary:

```
normal <-   read.table(text="  chr   start    end   length  abs_summit pileup   X.log10.pvalue. fold_enrichment
1  chr1   10004   10586    583      10076    288       262.84540        19.37227
2  chr1   28946   29387    442      29309     59        37.01597         8.33123
3  chr1  49999  386620   2165     385473     38        30.88671        10.66657
4  chr1  50000  546003   1227     545467     46        29.03529         7.95905
5  chr1  50001  547834    873     547696     37        21.86056         6.93344
6  chr1  564682  565377    696     565177   2396       801.42346         4.73626
7  chr1  565647  565859    213     565768   2225       677.54956         4.33460
8  chr1  566082  566749    668     566207   2363       767.32574         4.60286
9  chr1  567264  567682    419     567385   2559       900.85590         4.98421
10 chr1  569289  569585    297     569395   1994       535.04041         3.88158
11 chr1  603864  605365   1502     604917     28        20.02823         8.06871
12 chr1  713780  714492    713     714122     80        62.03205        12.10543
13 chr1  726303  726397     95     726331     35        20.22534         6.65208
14 chr1  726902  727015    114     726956     38        23.21246         7.27584
15 chr1  762303  763398   1096     762976     50        28.46482         7.09851
16 chr1  894589  894800    212     894677     58        28.29763         6.05185
17 chr1  912206  912835    630     912372     60        25.23332         5.16066
18 chr1 1013683 1014743   1061    1013926     67        28.39317         5.28122
19 chr1 1051254 1052109    856    1051607     76        45.31027         8.12284
20 chr1 1092833 1093509    677    1092949     50        21.65445         5.17642
", header=TRUE)
normal$bin=(normal$start+50000)%/%100000
normal$bin=(normal$start+50000)%/%100000
(normal_count1 = aggregate(end ~ chr + bin, data=normal, FUN=length))
#---
   chr bin end
1 chr1   0   3
2 chr1   1   2
3 chr1   6   6
4 chr1   7   3
5 chr1   8   1
6 chr1   9   2
7 chr1  10   1
8 chr1  11   2
```

If the problem is the appearance of the "0"-bin then subsetting is needed and the aggregate.formula function does have a 'subset' argument, so it would just be: `normal_count1 = aggregate(end ~ chr + bin, data=normal, FUN=length, subset= (start >= 50000) )`

Comment: This does it. I guess the problem was I was not creating the new column (`$bin`) and was changing the value of `start` instead? Many thanks!